How to input a u64 parameter in Anchor
I have a function which creates a lookup table
    pub fn create_lookup_table(
        ctx: Context<CreateLookupTable>,
        recent_slot: u64,
        _discriminator: u64,
    ) -> Result<()> {
 
//ommitted part of the code

// Create the lookup table
        let (lookup_instruction, table) =
        anchor_lang::solana_program::address_lookup_table::instruction::create_lookup_table_signed(
                ctx.accounts.authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                recent_slot,
            );
        if table != ctx.accounts.lookup_table.key() {
            return err!(ErrorCode::InvalidLookupTable);
        }

            
    //rest of the code
    }

I have set up a typescript test but this always fails with InvalidLookUpTable. Thus, the address derived inside the program is not the same as the one derived in the typescript test
 let recentSlot = await connection.getSlot();

  const [lookupTableAddress, bumpSeed] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [signer.publicKey.toBuffer(), new BN(recentSlot).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8)],
    program.programId,
  );

    const tx = await program.methods.createLookupTable(
      new BN(recentSlot),
      new BN(0),
    )
    .accounts({
      lookupTable: lookupTableAddress,
      payer: signer.publicKey,
      registryAccount: RegisteryAccount
    })
    .signers([signer])
    .rpc()


HOWEVER when I look at the code that derives the lookUptable in rust (function used by the program), and tried the code in Rust myself with the same parameters as in typescript, it gave me the same address! I am thus in great difficulty at attempting to debug this. Below is the code used to derive the address on chain
fn derive_lookup_table_address(
    authority_address: &Pubkey,
    recent_block_slot: Slot,
    id: &Pubkey
) -> (Pubkey, u8) {
    Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[authority_address.as_ref(), &recent_block_slot.to_le_bytes()],
        id,
    )
}


Are you using the correct program when deriving the LUT in TS? You have program.programId in your TS code, the expectation is the LUT program ("AddressLookupTab1e1111111111111111111111111")

That's exactly it ser, I thought it was the program address. Thanks a lot !!
